# Solutions of the Dirac equation via a predetermined probability density?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation

I’m trying to understand the Dirac equation and its general solutions better.

In particular, if one hypothetically knew *a priori* the explicit, normalized form of the probability density of a relativistic particle for a particular eigenstate $\psi$, such that $|\psi|^2 = C(E, p)$, how would one “work backwards” so to speak and write the full expression of $\psi$ as a unique solution of the Dirac equation?

In the case of a free particle, must $C(E, p)$ take a particular form or are arbitrary representations possible?

The more detailed the answer, the better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is $|\psi|^2$ when solutions of the Dirac equation have four components?

Comment: $|\psi|^2$ has four components, no?

Comment: So $C$ also does? Taking the square root of all four components of $C$ and plugging them into the Dirac equation will not give zero if $C$ is arbitrary.

Comment: The implication is that $\sqrt{C^\mu}$ is not arbitrary insomuch as it *does* give zero when plugged into the Dirac equation.